# How to list packages and their urls in yum repository?

Tags: yum

How can I list all the packages and their download URLs in a yum repository?

I tried

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=google-chrome list available
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Available Packages
google-chrome-beta.x86_64                32.0.1700.14-1            google-chrome
google-chrome-unstable.x86_64            33.0.1707.0-1             google-chrome
```

But that doesn't give the URLs and it's also missing one package that I happened to have installed (google-chrome-stable)

I also tried a http request to the baseurl but I got a 404 error

```
$ http --headers get http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64  
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

---

This is the repo if you'd like to try to reproduce

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional way to do it is:

```
repoquery --repoid=<whatever> -a --location
repoquery --repoid=<whatever> -a --qf '%{ui_nevra} %{location}'
```

...the later allowing you to see other bits of info. about the package as well.